# ¿Como leer una matriz desde un .txt? C#

Tags: c#, archivo, matrices

Necesito leer una matriz de x tamaño que este escrita en un archivo de texto, y mostrarla en un DataGridView.

El archivo debe ir escrito como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que llevo hasta ahora es el siguiente:
Tambien tengo este error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'" en `matriz[filas, i] = arreglo[i];`

```
        OpenFileDialog ofdAbrir = new OpenFileDialog(); //Objeto para abrir archivos
        ofdAbrir.Filter = "Text File |*.txt"; //Solo acepta .txt
        if (ofdAbrir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader srArchivo = new StreamReader(ofdAbrir.FileName);//Objeto para leer archivo
            
            using (srArchivo)
            {
                int f = 5;
                int c = 5;
                string[,] matriz = new string[f, c];

                
                
                while (!srArchivo.EndOfStream)
                {

                    for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz.Length; filas++)
                    {
                        string fila = srArchivo.ReadLine();

                        if (fila != null)
                        {
                            string[] arreglo = fila.Split(' ');

                            for (int i = 0; i < fila.Length; i++)
                            {
                                matriz[filas, i] = arreglo[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   
                   
                }
```

Comment: Podrías darle un voto a las respuestas que te hayan resultado útiles y marcar como aceptada la que más te haya gustado, gracias

Answer (score 1):

.
Hola.

Para el error en la [matriz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107357/multi-dimensional-arrays-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array) es necesario recorrer las dimensiones y poder asignar el arreglo según las posiciones.

Basándome en tu código:

```
while (!srArchivo.EndOfStream)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < matriz.GetLength(0); x++)
                    {
                        string fila = srArchivo.ReadLine();
                        if (fila != null)
                        {
                            string[] arreglo = fila.Split(' ');

                            for (int y = 0; y < matriz.GetLength(1); y++)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.Length; i++)
                                {

                                    matriz[x, y] = arreglo[i];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[,] matrix = new string[5, 5];
var lineas = File.ReadAllLines(ruta);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   string[] vector = lineas[i].Split();

   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
      matrix[i, j] = vector[j];
   }
}
```

Se declara una matriz de tipo **string** con 5 columnas y 5 filas (siguiendo tu ejemplo).
Posteriormente hacemos uso del **método** **ReadAllLines** de la **clase** **File** el cual nos va a devolver en un **arreglo string**(llamado lineas) todas las líneas del fichero, donde la primera posición del arreglo será la primera línea del fichero, la segunda posición del arreglo será la segunda línea y así sucesivamente.

Posteriormente procedemos al llenado de la matriz para ello declaramos dos **ciclos for anidados** e iremos aplicando la **función** **Split** línea por línea, separando de esta forma cada caracter de dicha línea, usando como caracter separador el espacio(' '). La **función** **Split** devolverá un nuevo arreglo donde cada posición de dicho nuevo arreglo será cada caracter de la línea separado por el caracter espacio(' '). Es este nuevo arreglo el que iremos usando para llenar cada fila de la matriz.